# Equivalent of "xlim" or "ylim" for vertical/horizontal abline?

Tags: r, graphics

I'm using the `abline` function in R to draw vertical lines on a plot. Is there a way I can restrict the extent of the line? For example, yf the Y axis goes from 0 to 4, can I plot just the portion from 0 to 2?

Comment: try the `segments()` function.

Comment: Yoo bad you didn't post an example. I have a solution that just cries out for one.

Comment: Wow, I don't understand the downvote without an explanation (unless that was you @BondedDust--I assumed not since it was delayed).

Comment: By the way @BenBolker, your suggestion worked nicely and would love to give you credit if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `segments()` function, e.g.

```
plot(1:4,1:4,ylim=c(0,4))
abline(v=2)
segments(x0=2,y0=0,x1=2,y1=2,col="red")
```